# Couldn't find file 'foundation_and_overrides'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey when i type "rake assets:precompile" on terminal it shows error like this

```
I, [2016-05-05T13:52:42.537665 #11661]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/paras/Hackathon_hackerearth/hackathon_1/public/assets/application-e73a0a56296d201e9779eb9ca13396a60e55ba64dee295f7fb3f1f39a64fee90.js
I, [2016-05-05T13:52:42.545034 #11661]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/paras/Hackathon_hackerearth/hackathon_1/public/assets/application-e73a0a56296d201e9779eb9ca13396a60e55ba64dee295f7fb3f1f39a64fee90.js.gz
rake aborted!
Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'foundation_and_overrides' with type 'text/css'
/Users/paras/Hackathon_hackerearth/hackathon_1/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css:17
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
zlib(finalizer): Zlib::GzipWriter object must be closed explicitly.
zlib(finalizer): the stream was freed prematurely.`
```

My Gem file is here

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 0.15'

gem 'pry'

#for password
gem 'bcrypt'

#for creating fake users
gem 'faker'

#for tagging 
gem 'foundation-rails'

#for rating
gem 'ratyrate'


#for pagination
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate'

#bootstrap
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
#gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
ruby "2.3.0"
gem 'puma'
```

here is my application.js file's data

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require foundation
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .


$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });
```

and here is my application.css file

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require foundation_and_overrides
 */
```

please tell me that what is wrong with it. i searched it but no hint could solve this error. i am working on OS X El Capitan.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a CSS file whose name starts with `foundation_and_overrides` in your `assets/stylesheets` folder?

It can't find it.